# Textview in android fragment duplicated in landscape layout

Tags: android, textview, fragment, landscape

I am trying to make an app with two fragments, one containing a list of groups (called OverviewFragment) and one fragment containing the details of selected group (called DetailsFragment). I want only one fragment to be visible at a time in portrait mode and both to be visible simultaneously in landscape mode.

I have two problems. First of all the transition between portrait and landscape is very unstable and leads to a variety of crashes, i.e: a blank screen, "No view found", "Error inflating class fragment" and "overlapping rendering".

My other more concrete problem is that when in landscape mode, the textview containing the group name is duplicated and added at the top of the layout. To me this is very strange since the other textview (containing the group info) does NOT get duplicated. Very puzzling!

Running the app in portrait mode alone works fine and I experience no crashes or duplicated textviews.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OverviewFragment.OnOverviewInteractionListener, DetailsFragment.OnDetailsInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { // if we are being restored we dont need to do stuff
            System.out.println("saved");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("tag is: "+findViewById(R.id.activity_main).getTag());

        if (findViewById(R.id.activity_main).getTag().equals("portrait")) {
            OverviewFragment overFrag = new OverviewFragment();
            System.out.println("PORTRAIT IF ---------------------");
            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, overFrag).commit();

        } else if (findViewById(R.id.activity_main).getTag().equals("landscape")) {
            System.out.println("LANDSCAPE IF ---------------------");
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.overview_fragment, new OverviewFragment());
            transaction.replace(R.id.details_fragment, new DetailsFragment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOverviewInteraction(int position) {
        DetailsFragment detailsFrag = (DetailsFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details_fragment);

        Group group = OverviewFragment.getGroups()[position];
        DetailsFragment newFragment = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("groupName", group.getName());
        args.putString("groupInfo", group.getInfo());
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (detailsFrag != null) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.details_fragment, newFragment);
        } else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetailsInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:tag="portrait"
    tools:context="com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml (land)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:tag="landscape">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition.OverviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/overview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition.DetailsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

OverviewFragment.java

```
package com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OverviewFragment extends ListFragment {

    private OnOverviewInteractionListener mListener;
    private static Group[] groups = {new Group("group 1", "5"), new Group("group 2", "13"),
            new Group("group 3", "12"), new Group("group 4", "32"), new Group("group 5", "45")};

    public OverviewFragment() {
    }

    public static OverviewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        OverviewFragment fragment = new OverviewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        List<String> groupNames = new ArrayList();
        for (Group g: groups
             ) {
            groupNames.add(g.getName());
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, groupNames));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mListener.onOverviewInteraction(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnOverviewInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnOverviewInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnOverviewInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnOverviewInteractionListener {
        void onOverviewInteraction(int position);
    }

    public static Group[] getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }
}
```

DetailsFragment.java

```
package com.example.o2k.lab2naviedition;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnDetailsInteractionListener mListener;
    private String groupName;
    private String groupInfo;

    public DetailsFragment() {
    }

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance() {
        DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
        TextView groupNameTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.groupNameText);
        TextView groupInfoTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.groupInfoText);
        if (this.getArguments() != null) {
            groupName = this.getArguments().getString("groupName");
            groupInfo = this.getArguments().getString("groupInfo");
        } else {
            groupName = "<emptyNAME>";
            groupInfo = "<emptyINFO>";
        }
        groupInfoTextView.setText("No of members: "+groupInfo);
        groupNameTextView.setText(groupName);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnDetailsInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnDetailsInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnDetailsInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnDetailsInteractionListener {
        void onDetailsInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in one case do you call `add`, in another - `replace`?

Comment: At the first it will be better to use same names for fragment containers in portrait and lanscape modes. And read about `retain fragments`. At the second put a full log of errors. Seems like you try to add a fragment twice.

Comment: Try to replace `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, overFrag).commit();` to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, overFrag).commit();`.

Comment: @Шах I am doing this because in the landscape layout i want to replace the placeholder fragments with the actual fragments. But in portrait I just want to add it to the screen. I am not sure this is the right way though, nice remark!

Comment: @Шах I tried using replace instead but the result is the same unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using FrameLayouts instead of your custom fragments in the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:tag="landscape">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/overview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your way, you are creating each fragment twice.
good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, this solved the duplication issue! Now all I gotta do is make the transition between landscape and portrait work (:

Comment: I think the way you check weather you are in portrait or landscap mode is wrong. now that you have two differnt layouts, you can check weather the "details_fragment" container is available. if it is you are in landscape mode: private boolean isLandscape(){ FramLayout detailsContainer = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.details_fragment);   IF(detailsContainer == null){ return false;}else{ return true;}}

Comment: After you do that you can use it in your MainActivity:   if(isLandscape){...initialize overviewFragment and detailsFragment...}else{....initialize only overviewFragment.....}